# Avr-gcc does not compile correctly without optimizations, but works (badly) with -Os

Tags: avr, c, attiny, avr-gcc, gcc

I am developing software for attiny88 with avr-gcc toolchain. This is a cheap microcontroller with 8kB program memory, 512B SRAM and 64B non-volatile EEPROM data memory. This is all sufficient for the task it is supposed to handle. I do not have a debugger for this chip.

The device acts as SPI slave and allows the master to read/program the EEPROM and to read the device state (state of some analog inputs and digital outputs). The protocol is simple - first databyte carries the instruction where highest two bits encode required action (00-nothing, 01-write eeprom, 10-read eeprom, 11-read state) and the rest is address. Second byte is always zero, third byte is the value to read or write, fourth byte is always zero.

Problem is that I am getting weird behavior from the compiler. It is difficult to put a finger on what is going on, so I will just give a few examples. Most striking is that without -Os optimization the device does not respond over SPI. This is not for any of the obvious reasons - the program fits the memory and the stack should not run into .bss/.data sections (the program has ~700B, SRAM is mapped between 0x100 and 0x2ff, where .bss_end is at 0x109; the heap is empty; there are no nested function calls, neither nested interrupts).

If I turn on the -Os optimization, then the program responds as intended. Here is the working code to handle the ISR:

```
unsigned char state[8];
volatile unsigned char data;

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  switch(data>>6) {
  case 0: 
    data = SPDR;
    break;
  case 1:           /* write eeprom */
    while(EECR & (1<<EEPE));
    EECR = (0<<EEPM1)|(0<<EEPM0);
    EEARL = 0;
    EEDR = SPDR;
    EECR |= (1<<EEMPE);
    EECR |= (1<<EEPE);
    data = 0;
    break;
  case 2:               /* read eeprom */
    EEARL = data & 0x1f;    /* with 0x3f stops working (???) */
    EECR |= (1<<EERE);
    SPDR = EEDR;
    data = 0;
    break;
  case 3:           /* read state */
    SPDR = state[data&7];
    data = 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

However, the program gets broken when written in semantically different way:

- If I change the line "EEARL = data & 0x1f;" to "EEARL = data & 0x3f;", which is desirable as it would allow to address whole EEPROM address space, the ERPROM writing/reading stops working (I do not need full 64B, so I left it as is)
- State reading (case 3) gets broken if I replace the line "SPDR = state[data&7];" with switch-case construct that returns value of PORTD/PORTB register when address is 0 and 1 respectively (the current workaround is to keep state[0] and state[1] synchronized with PORTB/PORTD in the main loop).

Am I missing something important? It seems to me that the compiler messes up, but I haven't found any bug reports for avr-gcc or avr-libc (newlib?) that would fit the bill.

The toolchain was installed from current gcc-avr package in aptitude repositories. The makefile is pretty basic:

```
all: main.hex main.s

main.elf: main.o
    avr-gcc -g -mmcu=attiny88 -o main.elf main.o

main.s: main.elf
    avr-objdump -d main.elf > main.s

main.hex: main.elf
    avr-objcopy -O ihex  main.elf main.hex

main.o: main.c
    avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny88 -Os -c main.c -Wall
```

**UPDATE**: Still the same result with latest binutils, gcc and avr-libc (recompiled from sources)

Comment: Try reading/comparing the generated machine code.

Comment: Where do you initialize the `data` variable? Are you relying on static initialization to give you "zero-out"? That's always a bad idea, since microcontrollers often deviate from the C standard there, in order to give faster start-up.

Comment: That being said, the most common reason by far why programs stop working between different levels of optimization, is that somewhere in your program, you have some manner of undefined behavior. That is, you probably have a dormant bug which surfaced when you changed the build. Not necessarily in the code posted.

Comment: @Lundin I initialize all during init, even avr-libc FAQ states that they do initialize variables (http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_varinit), I do not rely on that. The .data section is empty.

Comment: Years ago, certain routines in avr-libc were problematic is -O0.  I wonder if this is the case (e.g. see http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/optimization-levels-avr-studio )

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks for the suggestion, it occurred to me that I can diff the disassembly when I just change one constant from 0x1f to 0x3f as discussed in the question. The differences are vast - practically whole program is different. Seems wrong though - for example cli (disable interrupts) instruction disappeared from the interrupt handler routine

Comment: @Lundin You see most of the program, the rest is just init of all shared variables, init of SPI and an infinite loop. Full program looks different, but I am testing it on this minimal version that reproduces the bugs. I am not leaving trash in memory and preinitialize all manually. It is a simple program after all.

Comment: @Damien that might explain why it does not work without -Os (although I would like to know details why -O0 fails), but it still does not explain those bugs I describe. About the volatile keyword - data is volatile as I write to it from the ISR, state is just read from the ISR, so it does not need to be volatile.

Comment: Doing time taking things (like writing EEPROM ) inside an interrupt handler (recalled each SPI receiving event ) definitevely brings rotten luck.

Comment: @carloc Reading EEPROM halts the CPU for 4 cycles, write is done asynchronously with autonomous automata on chip - it does not block the CPU. The problem is not there.

Comment: Random observation #1: you need to do `while(EECR & (1<<EEPE));` before _reading_ the eeprom as well. Observation #2: I don't see how the 4-byte protocol you described works with your ISR - Example: eeprom write; the first byte will be read as command/address, the second (zero) byte will trigger the actual write, and write 0 to eeprom, the third byte (data) will again be interpreted as a command. That doesn't match  your described intention...

Comment: @marcelm I do not need to do the spinloop as long as I know that nobody will program the EEPROM just before reading from it. The spinloop when writing is there only as failsafe against mem corruption and should never actually spin. About the program - notice that the interrupt triggers when you finish transfer of a byte while the next byte can already be on the way. That is why there is the padding and why it works. It is fast, simple and requires only one global variable..

Comment: @marcelm My apologies, I wrote in the post that writing is done with the third byte, that is wrong - the databyte to write to EEPROM is second. Read data is still shifted out with the third byte.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to inspect the output of `avr-objdump` to see what exact instructions were generated for your code. Incidentally, it would be helpful to include your C code in the disassembly via `avr-objdump -S main.elf > main.s`. I doubt that the whole program becomes different when you replace the `0x1F` constant by `0x3F`, isolating differences in the listing and analyzing them carefully would be your next step.

Such analysis is about as far as you can get without proper development tools. Getting a debugger or a simulator would save you a lot of effort which is required when you're limited to static listing analysis.

PS: I assume here that you don't get any compiler warnings during compilation. If you have any, fixing those should be your first priority. Modern compilers do a pretty good job at informing you about subtle errors which may be hard to find otherwise.

Comment: There are no warnings with -Wall; Simulavr/debugger might be some use but since I have a version of the software that works in repeatable fashion it is not a problem on the the chip. About the differences due to change of a constant from 0x1f to 0x3f: Diff will mark most of the code as a rewrite. It boils down to extra variable in .bss section and changes in offsets in the program that change addressing literals. It is strange, but the program is structurally different - seems that the optimizer decides to use extra variable to speed thing up with 0x3f constant.

Comment: @student try to produce assembler listings from compiler, i.e. `avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny88 -Os -S main.c`. That should leave address literals in symbolic form (`label_0001` etc.), so producing a diff should be easier.